# Running a executable .jar file using .bat file from different location

Tags: batch-file, executable-jar

I want to run a executable .jar file through .bat file. But want to keep both files in different location. 
Currently file is being executed. but i'm keeping .jar and .bat in same location.
Kindly help me how to do it. Current .bat file details.

```
TITLE JAppium1.0
java -jar D:\Projects\Appium\Final\JAppium_FrameWork_V1.0\JAppium1.0.jar
```

Comment: then point the batch file path to the jar file, like you are already doing... I would however double quote paths for the possible scenarios where you have space in paths.

Comment: Seems like you've already got it figured out. Just do what you're already doing in the code.